# No public execute() in class org.apache.jasper.JspC

Tags: java

I got the error "No public execute() in class org.apache.jasper.JspC" when I tried to build(ant build) the xml file. could you please suggest a solution? thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have two different jar files on your classpath which contain different versions of `JspC`. (e.g. you could have `j2ee-[versionnumberhere].jar` on your classpath which contains another version of `JspC`)

Comment: you mean while setting the class path in the enviornment variable.